# Starting PlexMediaServer Service Seems to Break routing out of LAN

Tags: linux, networking

I noticed this behavior when starting a service (in this case, plexmediaserver), where I can connect to addresses outside of the LAN (resolution doesn't break, however, when referencing a DNS name instead of an IP) when the service is running:

```
user@miltons:~$ sudo systemctl stop plexmediaserver
user@miltons:~$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=117 time=23.4 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=117 time=22.9 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=117 time=23.9 ms
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 22.907/23.387/23.853/0.386 ms
user@miltons:~$ sudo systemctl start plexmediaserver
user@miltons:~$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
7 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 6142ms
```

and this seems to occur on every system I've tried this one (installed a .deb on Ubuntu 22.04, .rpm on a couple of Fedora hosts)-- I assume it is something specific to this service that is causing routing to break, but as far as I can tell, nothing else changes (routing table looks the same before and after stopping, no new iptables rules, nothing in dmesg, LAN traffic is undisrupted), starting this service just seems to result in all traffic to and from addresses outside of the LAN from connecting.

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp112s0
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp112s0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp112s0
192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 enp112s0
```

What other factors might be causing this, or places I may start looking (assuming, of course, the issue is not entirely contained in the use of the software itself)?

Comment: Before starting the service, keep these two commands running: `ip monitor` and `nft monitor ruleset`. start the service and retrieve their output. 95% of network changes would be there (some changes won't be caught by these commands though).

Comment: It was unclear what the cause of the issue was, as it occurred on every system and OS I tried it on, even after monitoring for changes, however, at least on Ubuntu 22.04, when I changed the netplan renderer to use NetworkManager (for an unrelated task, and decided to check on a whim), this behavior stopped occurring.

Comment: So are you giving up on finding the cause? Did you read the comment I wrote to help you at all?